# Mixing cooking chocolate with normal chocolate

Tags: chocolate, melting-chocolate, mixing, tempering

I have some cooking chocolate and I have some chocolate seashells. I've had the chocolate seashells for some time now and I want to use them because I don't want them to go to waste. So, I was thinking of mixing some of the chocolate seashells with the cooking chocolate to make chocolate cups (melt the chocolate together and use it to make chocolate cups) and then filling them with panna cotta. The question is if mixing the 2 types of chocolate a bad idea or if mixing just a small amount of chocolate seashells with the cooking chocolate work?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the types of chocolate that you have.  Is the cooking chocolate baking chocolate (1 oz squares)? And are the shells a pre-formed and tempered that's intended to be filled?

Comment: When you say cooking chocolate do you mean chocolate-flavoured cake coating like Scotbloc?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, by cooking chocolate I mean, the sort of chocolate you use to make chocolate cakes and brownies, etc. and by chocolate shells I mean, chocolate in seashell shapes. The reason why I mentioned seashells is because the chocolate seashells taste a bit different to something like a normal milk chocolate.

Comment: People use all sorts of chocolate to make chocolate cake or brownies. Also, manufacturers can shape anything into seashells. Please tell us the ingredients list if you want us to help, I still have no idea what you are trying to mix.

Comment: @rumtscho: I just simply want to melt and mix cooking chocolate with the normal milk chocolate. The recipes everywhere say that I should be using cooking chocolate, but I was wondering if the cooking and normal milk chocolate can be mixed or does it end up in disaster. Like I said before, the reason why I mentioned seashells is because the chocolate seashells taste a bit different to something like a normal milk chocolate like dairy milk.

Comment: This doesn't answer rumtschos question. The problem is that we can't help you when we don't know stuff like the fat content etc. If you want to be sure to avoid a disaster, just dissolve some chocolate in hot milk, making it a delicious hot chocolate to drink ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divi, I would try a sample melting of the two chocolates - do this very slowly in a double boiler or if you are super-careful, in a microwave - to see how the two chocolates react to being mixed once melted.

If they mix adequately, drop the test mix on a piece of wax paper and let it cool to see how the re-hardened mixture firms up.  Based on your experiment, you should have a better idea of what to expect with the two dissimilar chocolates.  (rumtscho has a good point that without knowing exactly what the two chocolates are, it's hard to give an answer.)

Comment: I added about 50gms of the milk chocolate to 200gms of dark chocolate and it turned out fine. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Divi, thanks for the update, I'm glad it worked out! :-)